In Ghidra, what if anything is the relationship between `FileSystem` and `GFileSystem`?
I've made some Ghidra Loaders and I'm now looking into making some FileSytems but first I have to understand some Ghidra's architecture.
In looking what other FileSystems do I've just noticed that there are actually two similarly named classes:

ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Base/src/main/java/ghidra/formats/gfilesystem/GFileSystem.java
ghidra/Ghidra/Framework/FileSystem/src/main/java/ghidra/framework/store/FileSystem.java

Are these two related in some way I need to understand or is it just a naming coincidence and should I therefore ignore the latter and concentrate on understanding the former?
